# How to create this doge fractal zoom?

Tags: image-processing, animation, fractals

I would like to learn how to recreate this fractal in Mathematica and make others in the same style:

https://m.imgur.com/r/FractalGifs/lYEK8Cd

[image]

Comment: The downvote is not from me but thinking about it, this might be easier with a unmanipulated image of the dog as a reference...

Comment: Combine a set of `AffineTransforms` and use those with `ImageTransformation` to adjust the original image padding around the edges with `0` (`Black`) then add them together

Comment: There is a related post [here](https://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/24/droste-effect-with-mathematica/) on the Wolfram Mathematica Blog.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Making the GIF

I'm bored so let me GIF this up for you. I whipped out my trusty lasoo tool to make a [no-background doge for you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM8Bu.png). The final result looks like this:

[image]

Here's how we use a variant of that IFS to make the frames of that GIF.

```
fadeFrame[sides_: 20, bottom_: 40] :=
  ImageEffect[
    ImageEffect[#, {"FadedFrame", sides, {Left, Right}}],
    {"FadedFrame", bottom, {Bottom}}
    ] &;

dogeImg2 =
  ImagePad[
      Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM8Bu.png"],
      {{0, 0}, {0, 100}},
      GrayLevel[1, 0]
      ] // ImageResize[#, Scaled[.5]] & //
    
    ImageTake[#, {.75, {.1, .85}}*Reverse@ImageDimensions[#] // 
       Apply[Sequence]] & // fadeFrame[];

dogeIFS2 =
  With[{scales = {1/5, 1/3}},
   With[{
     transfs = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]/# & /@ scales,
     shifts = {{0.26, .98}, {0.65, .95}}/scales
     },
    MapThread[
     AffineTransform[{#, -#2}] &,
     {transfs, shifts}
     ]
    ]
   ];

dogesRaw =
  Table[
   ImageCompose[#, makeIFSImage[#, dogeIFS2, 4]] &@
    ImageResize[dogeImg2, Scaled[scaling]],
   {scaling, 1, 3, .1}
   ];
    
    dogeIFS2 =
      With[{scales = {1/5, 1/3}},
       With[{
         transfs = DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]/# & /@ scales,
         shifts = {{0.26, .98}, {0.65, .95}}/scales
         },
        MapThread[
         AffineTransform[{#, -#2}] &,
         {transfs, shifts}
         ]
        ]
       ];
    
    doges =
      Table[
       ImageTake[
        makeIFSImage[
         ImageResize[dogeImg2, Scaled[scaling]],
         dogeIFS2,
         4
         ],
        Sequence @@
         Times[
          {1, -1},
          Reverse@ImageDimensions[
            dogeImg2
            ]
          ]
        ],
       {scaling, 1, 3, .1}
       ];
```

Your computer will churn for a while while it makes all those images, but you get a pretty good result. Then we'll stabilize the images and take only the region of interest for a nice GIF:

```
topWhiteSpacePadding = 14; (*these are fudge factors to make the GIF stableish *)
rightWhiteSpacePadding = 7;

dogesProcessed =
  Table[
   With[
    {
     dims1 = ImageDimensions[doge],
      dims2 = ImageDimensions[dogeImg2]
     },
    With[{scaling = dims1[[2]]/dims2[[2]]},
     (*fadeFrame[0, 0]@*)
     ImageTake[
      doge,
      {
        0,
        dims2[[2]]
        } + (scaling - 1)*topWhiteSpacePadding,
      {
        dims1[[1]] - dims2[[1]],
        dims1[[1]]
        } - (scaling - 1)*rightWhiteSpacePadding
      ]
     ]
    ],
   {doge, dogesRaw}
   ];
```

Finally we export with some other GIF-specific tweaks:

```
Export["~/Desktop/dogeGif.gif", 
 dogesProcessed[[2 ;;]], 
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity,
  "DisplayDurations" ->
  Join[
   ConstantArray[.06, 10],
   ConstantArray[.02, 10]
   ]
 ]
```

And in the end you have that GIF up there.

## Original

Here's a fun example. We'll use this basic doge:

[image]

Then we fade the frame, define our IFS, and doge away:

```
dogeImg = 
  ImageEffect[
   Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/igIrh.png"], {"FadedFrame", 40}];

dogeIFS =
  With[{scale = 1/3},
   With[{D = 1/scale*DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]}, {
     AffineTransform[{D, -{0.26, 0.80}/scale}],
     AffineTransform[{D, -{0.6, 0.7}/scale}]
     }]
   ];

makeIFSImage[dogeImg, dogeIFS]
```

[image]

#### Code

Here's the approach I mentioned in my comment:

```
imageIFS[imgs_List, funs_List] :=
  Flatten@Table[
    ImageTransformation[img, fn,
     DataRange -> Automatic,
      Padding -> Transparent
     ],
    {img, imgs},
    {fn, funs}
    ];
imageIFS[img_?ImageQ, funs_List] :=
  imageIFS[{img}, funs];
makeIFSImage[img_?ImageQ, funs_List, iterations_: 4] :=
 
 Fold[ImageCompose,
  Flatten@
   NestList[
    imageIFS[#, funs] &,
    img,
    iterations
    ]
  ]
```

When applied to the Sierpinski triangle with a sample test image it looks like this:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}];

sierpinksiGasketFS =
  With[{D = 2*DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]}, {
    AffineTransform[{D}],
    AffineTransform[{D, -{1, 0}}],
    AffineTransform[{D, -{0, 1}}]
    }];

makeIFSImage[img, sierpinksiGasketFS]
```

[image]

You can easily tweak `sierpinksiGasketFS` to get it to position the images differently and scale them differently.

Another version could be done just using `Graphics` and `Inset` and using a basic IFS to generate to points for the inset but I'll leave that for someone else.

Comment: Oh wait, but it doesn't zoom 

Comment: @user5601  if you want it to be a GIF like that try modifying the input image to zoom on that for like 10 different scaling factors and make a GIF with `"AnimationRepetitions"->Infinity`

Answer (score 7):

I didn't bother generating the nested fractal still since I don't have the original image. But here's how to semi-eyeball an animation with the still provided by OP. Because of this, my GIF will lose noticeable quality as it zooms.

First let's remove the watermark:

```
doge = RemoveAlphaChannel[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGfAi.jpg"]];

mask = Dilation[DeleteSmallComponents[# - DeleteSmallComponents[#] &[Binarize[im, .1]]], 2];

doge = Inpaint[im, mask]
```

[image]

Next I used the interactive coordinates tool to find the coordinates of 2 noses.

[image]

The coordinates I picked:

```
pts = {{227, 360}, {133, 244}};
HighlightImage[doge, pts]
```

[image]

It's clear we need to translate the top point to the bottom point, but how much should we scale by? We can minimize the error through `FindMinimum`.

```
translated = ImagePerspectiveTransformation[
  doge, 
  TranslationTransform[Subtract @@ pts], 
  Padding -> "Fixed",
  DataRange -> Full
];

scaledoge[t_?NumericQ] := ImagePerspectiveTransformation[
  translated, 
  ScalingTransform[{t, t}, First[pts]], 
  Padding -> "Fixed", 
  DataRange -> Full
]

t /. Last[Quiet@FindMinimum[ImageDistance[doge, scaledoge[t]], {t, 4.25}]]
```

> ```
> 4.14845
> ```

I'll round this to 4.15 and find the frames. Note that I scale the rate by a power of 1.5 to make the gif smoother.

```
frames = Most @ Table[
  ImagePerspectiveTransformation[
    doge, 
    ScalingTransform[(3.15 t + 1) {1, 1}, {t, 1 - t}.pts]@*TranslationTransform[{t, 1 - t}.pts - Last[pts]], 
    Padding -> "Fixed", 
    DataRange -> Full
   ], 
   {t, Range[0, 1, 1/24]^1.5}
];

Export["doge_fractal.gif", frames, AnimationRepetitions -> ∞, "DisplayDurations" -> 1/24];
```

[image]

Lastly, here's a comparison between the original image and the translated and scaled one:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

A real doge: [His Serenity Leonardo Loredan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_Loredan), the 75th Doge of Venice, with due credit to Bellini and Chip Hurst:

```
im = Import[
   "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Giovanni_Bellini%2C_portrait_of_Doge_Leonardo_Loredan.jpg"];

doge0 = ImageTake[im, {140, 4226 - 500}];

ctr = {1893, 3345};
doge = ImageCompose[doge0, 
   ImageResize[doge0, ImageDimensions@doge0/10], ctr];

doge = ImageCompose[doge0, 
   ImageResize[doge, ImageDimensions@doge0/10], ctr];

tfun = Last@FindGeometricTransform[
    {{0, 0}, ImageDimensions@doge},
    {ctr - ImageDimensions@doge0/20,
     ctr + ImageDimensions@doge0/20}
    ];

frames = Most@Table[
    ImageResize[
     ImagePerspectiveTransformation[
      doge, {IdentityMatrix[2] (1 - t) + t #[[All, ;; 2]], 
         t Flatten@#[[All, 3]]/First@ImageDimensions@doge} &@
       Most@TransformationMatrix[tfun]],
     ImageDimensions@doge/8.],
    {t, Range[0, 1, 1/24]^1.5}];

Export["/tmp/doge_fractal.gif", frames, 
  AnimationRepetitions -> ∞, "DisplayDurations" -> 1/24];
```

[image]

(Having placed the inset images, the transformation was easier to find.  One could derive it by hand as well.)

---

We can use `Inpaint` to make the background of the GIF constant.

```
im = Import[
   "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Giovanni_Bellini%2C_portrait_of_Doge_Leonardo_Loredan.jpg"];

bluecoverage = DominantColors[im, Automatic, "CoverageImage"][[1]];

mask = Dilation[DeleteSmallComponents[ColorNegate[bluecoverage]], 
   DiskMatrix[100]];

bg = Blur[
   DeleteSmallComponents[
    ColorNegate[DeleteSmallComponents[bluecoverage, 500]]], 10];

imsmall = ImageResize[ImageTake[im, {140, 4226 - 500}], Scaled[1/8]];
masksmall = ImageResize[ImageTake[mask, {140, 4226 - 500}], Scaled[1/8]];

background = 
  Inpaint[imsmall, masksmall, 
   Method -> {"TextureSynthesis", 
     "Masking" -> ColorNegate[masksmall]}];

{background, SetAlphaChannel[im, bg]}
```

[image]

```
doge0 = ImageTake[SetAlphaChannel[im, bg], {140, 4226 - 500}];

ctr = {1893, 3345};
doge = ImageCompose[doge0, 
   ImageResize[doge0, ImageDimensions@doge0/10], ctr];

doge = ImageCompose[doge0, 
   ImageResize[doge, ImageDimensions@doge0/10], ctr];

tfun = Last@
   FindGeometricTransform[{{0, 0}, 
     ImageDimensions@doge}, {ctr - ImageDimensions@doge0/20, 
     ctr + ImageDimensions@doge0/20}];

frames = Most@
   Table[RemoveAlphaChannel[
     ImageCompose[background, 
      ImageResize[
       ImagePerspectiveTransformation[
        doge, {IdentityMatrix[2] (1 - t) + t #[[All, ;; 2]], 
           t Flatten@#[[All, 3]]/First@ImageDimensions@doge} &@
         Most@TransformationMatrix[tfun]], 
       ImageDimensions[background]]]], {t, Range[0, 1, 1/24]^1.5}];

Export["/tmp/doge_fractal.gif", frames, 
  AnimationRepetitions -> ∞, "DisplayDurations" -> 1/24];
```

[image]